# How do I change "date field" format of a "view" in the form of a page in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, view, cck

I'm trying to show a list of dates of Nodes using view. The list should be something like,

- 19 September 2009
- 20 September 2009

Right now it can only show like

- Thu, 2009-11-12 (All day)
- Mon, 2009-11-09 (All day)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

admin/config/regional/date-time/formats and you can create custom formats and use it in views.
remember to clear cache and reload the views edit page, otherwise you won't see the new formats.

Comment: +1, just an additional note that in D7 this is now located at admin/config/regional/date-time/formats instead.

Comment: Updated the answer, D6 is history by now.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for barraponto's answer.  Also, check out the following link for a tutorial based article on setting the format how you would like, [Format Dates at Level Ten](http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/dustin-currie/format-dates-drupal)